# Is it possible to map amazon S3 to a EC2 micro-instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I just created a Amazon Linux micro-instance and setup a S3 bucket & an EC2+EBS. I want to know, if at all it is possible, to map a S3 to an EC2 instance, preferably via ssh, and not from the console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if I understand you correctly, you want to mount a S3 bucket in your EC2 instance? If yes, google s3fs or use this handy link https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=155722.

Comment: silly question, but do the commands and all have to be run from the ec2 instance?